# JQuery UI Tabs not working in IE11 on Magento 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, magento2

I'm unable to get JQuery UI Tabs to work within my magento 2 application. They work completely fine in all browsers except ie11 and below so stumped about what's going on. I'm including JQuery & JQuery UI using Require to load them into my document.

JQuery Version - 1.12.4
JQuery UI Version - v1.10.4

I've read all the current examples of fixes and implemented them, (Different doc.ready variation etc), Only IE experiencing problems.

```
require([
    "jquery","jquery/ui"
], function($){
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
        $( "#more-tabs1" ).tabs();
        $( "#more-tabs2" ).tabs();
        $( "#more-tabs3" ).tabs();
});
```

The JS, very basic implementation.

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">Hair</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Gentlemen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Beauty</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div id="tabs-1">
            <div id="more-tabs1">
                <ul class="ui-tabs-nav">
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-1">Cut &amp; Finish</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-2">Colour</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-3">Conditioning</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-4">Extensions</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="nested-tabs-1">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div id="nested-tabs-2">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div id="nested-tabs-3">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div id="nested-tabs-4">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
            <div id="more-tabs2">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-1">Grooming</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="nested-tabs-1">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
            <div id="more-tabs3">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-1">Manicures &amp; Pedicures </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-2">Threading </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#nested-tabs-3">Makeup &amp; Nails </a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="nested-tabs-1">
                    <p>Coming Soon</p>
                </div>
                <div id="nested-tabs-2">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
                <div id="nested-tabs-3">
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The HTML (Inside a Magento 2 Block)

Expected result is to function like the other browsers, correctly applying the tabs logic and making them clickable/work - Not getting any error messages in the console on any browser.

Sorry if things seem a bit vague it's my first post, Will supply more information if necessary

Comment: Please try to use IE browser F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? using the F12 Network tools to check whether the JQuery reference and the JQuery UI reference load success? Besides, please check whether you are using other front-end framework or a plugin. Perhaps they are not compatible.

Comment: @ZhiLv-MSFT No console errors, Loading the JS successfully, Will explore further about other plugins but don't believe so